# How to put google analytics script PHP to my sites?

Tags: google-analytics

I apply a Google analytics service. I got a code.

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'MY UA CODE', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

My drupal use AT Commerce this theme. Where do I put this code to my folder's file? There is an optional method. The php is here where I want to add to my block and let it call the above script.

<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>

Do I follow the same name analyticstracking.php or just add the above script to an existed php file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install module [Google Analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics). Or paste script to file html.tpl.php.